# Why can't R CMD BATCH allow your scripts to access the system’s standard input, while Rscript can?

Tags: r

*R in a Nutshell* says

> One key disadvantage of running R using the command R CMD BATCH is that your
>   scripts cannot access the system’s standard input. Luckily, there is a second com-
>   mand for running R in batch mode: the RScript command.

*An Introduction to R* says

> `R CMD BATCH`: Run R in batch mode. Runs `R --restore --save` with possibly further options (see `?BATCH`).

*An Introduction to R* says that [`R` commands have two forms](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line):

```
R [options]
```

and

```
R CMD command args
```

What `R [options]` command is equivalent to

```
R CMD BATCH "--args arg1 arg2" foo.R
```

?

What `R [options]` command is equivalent to

```
Rscript foo.R arg1 arg2
```

?

Why can't `R CMD BATCH` allow your scripts to access the system’s standard input?

Why can `Rscript`?

Thanks.

Comment: Basically `R CMD BATCH "--args arg1 arg2" foo.R` and `Rscript foo.R arg1 arg2` do the same thing, do they not? As to why or why not, well, that was just a design decision. `R` has been the main entry point to the interactive console. It makes sense to have a different entry point for traditional command line file processing: `Rscript`. I'm not sure what kind of answer you are looking for here.

Comment: Sorry that  my questions are not clear to you. *An Introduction to R* says that `R` commands have two forms: `R` can be followed by either `[options]` or `CMD`. See if you can understand my questions better now.

Comment: I added a link for your reading. Hopefully help you understand my questions. I am doing what I wrote in my post

Comment: You added the phrase "two forms." That's not really what the R introduction is saying. It's saying that you can either open the R console on the command line with `R`. Or you can can run different R utility/procedures not intending to open an R console with the `CMD` option when calling `R`. It does not imply at all that you can can do everything using either syntax nor are they equivalent. They are for different purposes but both still "run" the R executable. `Rscript` was a later addition to R added to solve the limitations of the `CMD BATCH` options.

Comment: `CMD` is not an option. I would not focus on this misuse of term, but on the questions that I asked. As far as I understand, both `R CMD BATCH` and `Rscript` invoke some `R [options]` commands. I was asking what those `R [options]` commands are, and why `R CMD BATCH` doesn't allow  a script to accept input from standard input, while `Rscript` can.

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but perhaps one of the reasons `Rscript` was created was because `R CMD BATCH` didn't allow a script to accept input from standard input, and that was seen as a problem. So they created `Rscript` to address the issue. As MrFlick says, *"`Rscript` was a later addition to R added to solve the limitations of the `CMD BATCH` options."*

Answer (score 2):

So with the current version of R, the CMD options are basically just wrappers to R scripts. You can find the UNIX version of there scripts [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/tree/06185bd431beb9b6e0883193273d1779ef2c6a2c/src/scripts) and it looks like the windows versions are embed in code [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e836ed8e12223ba970d06d04837c65e98e5296c5/src/gnuwin32/front-ends/rcmdfn.c).

However Rscript is built as a different executable. It is not the same as just running R with different options. The main reason for that is that R assumes that if there is anything coming in from standard input, then it should be interpreted as code to run. But Rscript was written to interpret the standard input as data. So as long as you aren't reading from standard input, there's not really a differences between Rscript and R CMD BATCH.